# Amazon Security Groups: Change Inbound SSH Port

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, port

How can I change the Inbound SSH Port on my Amazon Security Group?  When adding a new rule for SSH, the Port defaults to 22 and cannot be edited.

Is this possible?

Please note:  This question is not asking how to add an inbound rule to an Amazon security group.
It is also not asking how to change the ssh port in sshd_config.
This question is also not asking if security by obscurity is a good strategy.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'ssh port' in Amazon SG is just shortcut for tcp port 22. You should be perfectly ok with adding Custom TCP rule with whichever port you run your TCP on.

As far as I'm aware, Amazon SG is purely layer 4 filter, so it doesn't care about what is actually protocol used.

Comment: This answer is entirely correct, +1.